# Mariadb Database gets stuck with wordpress "Creating sort index"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, mariadb

Hello dear StackOverflow community,

I have a large  WordPress site that now crashes the database by creating dozens of **Creating sort index tasks** with:

```
SELECT t.*, tt.* 
FROM wp_terms AS t 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('categories') 
ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

Those run for more than 20 seconds +. Afterwards its "sending data" with the same SQL query. The server is using an AMD epyc cpu and shouldn't have any problems (even though the database is large) and it did not have until it suddenly seems to be stuck.

Shouldn't it be caching this query anyways?

The mariadb my.cf config looks like:

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#

user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir         = /usr/share/mysql
lc-messages             = en_US
skip-external-locking

# Broken reverse DNS slows down connections considerably and name resolve is
# safe to skip if there are no "host by domain name" access grants
#skip-name-resolve

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

#
# * Fine Tuning
#

#key_buffer_size        = 128M
#max_allowed_packet     = 1G
#thread_stack           = 192K
#thread_cache_size      = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
#myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64

#
# * Logging and Replication
#

# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# Recommend only changing this at runtime for short testing periods if needed!
#general_log_file       = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log            = 1

# When running under systemd, error logging goes via stdout/stderr to journald
# and when running legacy init error logging goes to syslog due to
# /etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf
# Enable this if you want to have error logging into a separate file
#log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
#long_query_time        = 10
#log_slow_verbosity     = query_plan,explain
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#min_examined_row_limit = 1000

# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
#max_binlog_size        = 100M

# * Character sets
#

# MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

#
# * InnoDB
#

# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
# Most important is to give InnoDB 80 % of the system RAM for buffer use:
# https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_size
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.5 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.5]
```

I restarted mariadb, but the advisor mentions a huge rate of opening tables (same for files). The server is running only for 15 minutes. Is this due to the short time or do I have to change the settings (before the huge amount of Creating sort index tasks, the server was stable)

> ```
> Issue:
> The rate of opening tables is high.
> Recommendation:
> Opening tables requires disk I/O which is costly. Increasing table_open_cache might avoid this.
> Justification:
> Opened table rate: 1.26 per second, this value should be less than 10 per hour
> Used variable / formula:
> Opened_tables / Uptime
> Test:
> value*60*60 > 10
> ```

I would be awesome if somebody has an idea, what to do about that problem

Comment: Profiling is often useless -- "sending data" does not mean "sending data".

Comment: How many rows did it return?  Is there in index on `taxonomy`?

Comment: I disagree with "opening tables is high"; 1.26/sec is OK.  Sure, there will be a spike when you restart.  That is normal, too.

Comment: Is a FULLTEXT index involved?